# Scope function is getting called multiple times in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am dynamicaaly adding Li elements in which i have attached scope function .But when i am clicking on that it gets called multiple times.
Please see this fiddle demo where i am getting this issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/udmcv/260/

**The Html is as below**

```
<div style="border:solid;color:red;Margin-bottom:4px;">
Click on Create Button to Generate the required li'sThe issue is that when there multiple Li  the corresponding is getting called multiple time
<ul id="ulTabList" >
</ul>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
<input type="button" ng-click="Addli()" value="Create"/>
</div>
```

and below is the Angular Code that i am using

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $compile) {
var workGroupTab ="TestA"
$scope.Addli =function(){
    var el = $("#ulTabList").append('<li ng-click="OpenWorkGroupTab();">Text of Li</li>'
    +'<input id="btnClose_4341" type="button" value="btn"  style="margin-left:1px;" ng-click="fn_btnClose()">');

  $compile(el.contents())($scope);
  }  
    $scope.fn_btnClose = function(){
        console.log('clicked'+ 'val');
    }

    $scope.OpenWorkGroupTab =function(){
     console.log('val2');
    }
})
```

I have also seen some post which says some suggestion but that din't work for me.
The issue is like suppose when i have 3 li genrated then on click of first Li button it  gets called 3 times.
When i am clicking on 2nd Li button it's getting called 2 times and so on.

Please suggest some idea for this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: why you not use `ng-repeat`???

Comment: Don't manually add to the DOM like this. You should be manipulating data structures which bind to the view to create what you want... not manipulate the view manually.

Comment: @Grundy :Actually I want the li element get generated and appended to Ul on button's click only

Comment: use `ng-repeat` with a scope array.

Comment: @rahulrathore, so just add element in array on button click

Comment: also you generate not valid html because insert input inside ul directly

Comment: Take jQuery.js completely out of your app and use angular methodology

Comment: It happens because you compile content of UL each time you add element therefore you attach multiple listeners to the element

Comment: @Maurycy: Thanks for your suggestion it worked ! I changed my code from $compile(el.contents())($scope);  To $("#ulTabList").append($compile($el)($scope));  and it worked for me.Thanks and Happy new year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advice you agains that kind of alteration with jQuery, angular is an MVC framework which means that VIEW should be driven by MODEL from CONTROLLER

but sometimes it is inevitable to do so, i've altered your code http://jsfiddle.net/udmcv/274/

```
var el = angular.element('<li ng-click="OpenWorkGroupTab();">Text of Li</li>'
    +'<input id="btnClose_4341" type="button" value="btn"  style="margin-left:1px;" ng-click="fn_btnClose()">');

  $compile(el)($scope);
  $("#ulTabList").append(el)
```

so it would compile only once per element, not content of UL which was causing multiple event attached

Comment: Thanks MauryCY for your help.

Comment: Hi Maurycy:
Can you please help me in this angular js problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616568/scope-function-inside-li-element-is-not-getting-called?noredirect=1#comment56984436_34616568

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and array, without jQuery

```
<ul id="ulTabList" >
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="button" value="btn"  style="margin-left:1px;" ng-click="fn_btnClose()">
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.items = [];

$scope.Addli = function(){
    $scope.items.push(1);//in your case not matter what objects in array because you not use it inside view
}
```

[Edited JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/udmcv/275/)

Answer (score 0):

A mistake I made when going from a jQuery environment to an Angular environment is wanting to use jQuery for everything, because I knew how it worked. A post that really helped me was this ["“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). It explains "The Angular way" of doing web applications.

In your case you could (as suggested multiple times) use Angular's `ng-repeat` attribute to add list items. The way this works is you define the items you want to have in an array in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.items = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3'
];
```

And then you can access that scope variable in your view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

This will produce:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">Item 1</li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">Item 2</li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now, in your controller you can add a function that adds an item to that list. Like this:

```
$scope.addItem = function(string) {
  $scope.items.push(string);
}
```

And call that function from your view:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="addItem('Item ' + items.length)" value="Create"/>
```

This will add an item to the list and (because Angular works that way) also adds a `<li>` element to the HTML.